# How to use angular module in other module and its store as state property of second module

Tags: angular, ngrx-store

I have an angular app where I have different modules and each module have its own store as a feature. Let's say there is module X and I want to use this module in module Y, now Y module have multiple tabs where this X module will be used, so basically I want store state of X module as part of Y module each tab's state property. How I can achieve this? May be my approach is not correct and I have to think the other way.

Answer (score 2):

When you define your module, you will have some code like this:

```
export const MODULE_Z_REDUCER_TOKEN = new InjectionToken<ActionReducerMap<StateZ>>('Z_REDUCERS', { factory: () => reducers });
```

and

```
 StoreModule.forFeature('some_value_as_key_z', MODULE_Z_REDUCER_TOKEN , {}),
```

The result will be in your store:

```
{
  some_value_as_key_z: {}
}
```

What I'm trying to explain is : a store is **GLOBAL**. You can't create a store inside a store.

So basically, what you want is a store with :

```
{
  store_y:{
     tab1: {},
     tab2: {},
     tab3: {},
   }
}
```

You can create inside your store Y, a state with tab1, tab2 and tab3. No need for a store in your module X.

Comment: so what you are saying is that Module X will not have a store and it will provide us with its reducers and we can use those reducers with a key where we want. I want to use module X in multiple modules, some of them have tabs and some will not have tabs, but this solution should work in all cases right?

Comment: In module X, your components will emit the change in higher component from Y/Z. And in Y/Z, you will intercept the emission and do what you want with it (store in Y store and store in Z store). This is one solution. But others exist but is too complex for only commentaries

Answer (score -1):

```
const state = {
developers: [{
name: 'Bilal',
competency: ['ASP.NET', 'Angular']
}]
};
export const getAllDevelopers =
createSelector(getState,
(state): Developer[] => {
return state && state.developers;
}
);
this.store.select<Developer[]>(getAllDevelopers).subscribe(
developers => console.log(developers)
);
```